# Converting Array of Struct to Json in Hive

Tags: json, struct, hive

I have a table in hive with the complex data type ( ARRAY<STRUCT< ). I have to export this data to an external system. In order to consume this data for the external system, we need to keep the JSON format for the struct column. Is there any in-built function which does the same for hive/spark. I can see a couple of posts suggesting 'Brickhouse.jar'. But for this scenario, we can not add any external jars to the repo.

For example, my struct column data is like this which is an array

ARRAY<STRUCT<`attribute1`:STRING, `updated_at`:TIMESTAMP, `partitionInfo`:STRING, `status`:BOOLEAN>>

The Output should look like for a single row

[
{"attribute1":"val11","updated_at":"val12","partitionInfo":"val13","status":"val14"},{"attribute1":"val21","updated_at":"val22","partitionInfo":"val23","status":"val24"},..
]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you include details like your attempt, input and the expected output?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Added more details about the column value

Answer (score 0):

in hue (hive's UI), you can use to_json function to convert Array of Struct  to json.
like

```
SELECT tid, to_json(orders) AS ordersJson FROM amz_trade limit 10;
```